# How can I safely give the user an access_token with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I was going to use `$facebook->getAccessToken()` but looking at the code it seemed like it'd give the user the application access token (via `getApplicationAccessToken()`) if it was unable to return a result from `getUserAccessToken()`. If I'm right, that means that passing the user an access token from `getAccessToken()` could under certain circumstances return the API secret.

How can I safely get an access token?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getUser()` to ensure that you have a current user session prior to returning the access token. **EDIT**: as mentioned in the comments, it seems this will not work with how Facebook's PHP client functions. A user's cookie can contain their user ID but also an invalid (expired) `code`. The PHP client will try to exchange the `code` for a user access token and fail. So `getUser()` will return a user ID while `getAccessToken()` will return an app access token. `getUser()` is not a valid way to check for a valid user access token.

If you want to be extra careful about it: Facebook app tokens all of the form of `<app id>|<some hash, possibly your secret>`. You could ensure that the access token you are returning does not have that format:

```
$token = $fb->getAccessToken();
$tokenParts = explode('|', $token, 2);
if ($tokenParts[0] != <your_app_id>) {
    return $token;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I've found that getUser sometimes returns my user id even if the session info is invalid.

Comment: I've noticed this recently as well. I'm not sure if you have found the same: the JS client can drop a signed_request in to a cookie that contains a valid user ID but an invalid "code" (the thing required to exchange for the user access token in this flow). Seems like a bug in the way the FB client handles this.

Comment: I think I'd consider this a bug as well. I accidentally leaked the client secret to anyone that had an expired session. Luckily, I could reset it (and I did) but now there's this getuser issue. *sigh* at least my app's working alright if the session is fine.